# How to duplicate records where value equals to x?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `YearLeave` which holds `**leave types records**` for different users, it looks as follows

```
ID,UserName,LeaveType,Year
```

currently there is 6000 leave type `where year = '2017'`

I need to **duplicate** `LeaveType` `where year = '2017'` and set year to `'2018'`

also maintain the correct `PrimaryKey (ID)`

Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
insert into yearleave (UserName, LeaveType, Year)
    select UserName, LeaveType, 2018
    from yearleave
    where year = 2017;
```

This assumes that `id` is assigned automatically.  It should an identity column, in which case that is true.

Comment: I think `UNION ALL` will do the job

Comment: Brilliant Gordon Linoff!

Comment: You mention you want to maintain the correct PK ID, if you mean to have a copy of an existence one, then make sure to add it with the SELECT